# Local data in isolated scope of directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing one of my first directives and I want to create some stub data in directive's scope.

Here is directive:

```
angular.fraskDirectives.directive("recipientsSelector", [

  function() {
      return {
          restrict: "E",
          replace: true,
          scope: {
             recipients: "=",
             theText: "test",
             users: [{
                 username: "aaa"
             }, {
                 username: "aab"
             }, {
                 username: "abb"
             }, {
                 username: "bbb"
             }, {
                 username: "bbc"
             }]
         },
         templateUrl: "partials/recipientsSelector.html"
     };
   }
]);
```

and here is template:

```
<div>
<div contenteditable>
    <p>{{theText}}</p>
</div>

<ul class="suggestions">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        {{user.username}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

But neither "text" field nor user field are not bound. I mean ul is empty and `{{text}}` looks like "`{{text}}`" on the page.

How could I create local data in my directive's isolated scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate the scope with only "local" data which is not bound to anything outside the directive, use a link function  like below:

```
angular.fraskDirectives.directive("recipientsSelector", [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            recipients: "=" // note that theText and users are missing
        },
        templateUrl: "partials/recipientsSelector.html",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.theText = "test";
            scope.users = [{
                username: "aaa"
            }, {
                username: "aab"
            }, {
                username: "abb"
            }, {
                username: "bbb"
            }, {
                username: "bbc"
            }];
        }
    };
}]);
```

An alternative would be to assign a controller to the directive and populate the scope in the controller.

Comment: And how can I add two way binding for both theText and users?

Comment: If you want two way binding, then put `theText: "="` and `users: "="` like for recipients in the scope property below replace (where I made the comment). To populate the variables once again use the link function or a controller.